# deviceready event is never fired in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, dom-events

I have a Sencha Touch application that should only start loading after the phonegap [`deviceready`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready) event was fired by phonegap.

The microloader is called by

```
Ext.blink({
    id:"8b19cfab-9dd1-44d0-892e-28f50a42aecd",
    js:[
        {path:"app.js",update:"full",version:"0.3.5"}
    ],
    css:[
        {path:"resources/css/app.css",update:"full",theme:"Default"},
        {path:"resources/css/sch.css",update:"full"}
    ]
});
```

Directly before this call, I added the following:

```
if(document.URL.indexOf('file://')==0) {
    var oldBlink = Ext.blink;
    Ext.blink = function(options) {
        window.alert('Adding deviceready event listener.');
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
            window.alert('Deviceready event listener was fired.');
            oldBlink(options);
        }, false);
    }
}
```

Now, the two window.alert calls were added simultaneously and for debugging purposes only. Only the first one fires. So no caching problem or anything, I just have to assume that the `deviceready` event doesn't fire at all, at least during the first five minutes until my phone's screen switches off.

Why could that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

tl;dr: `cordova.js` AKA `phonegap.js` was not added to the project.

Long version:

I'm sorry, the issue cannot be found in the code I posted, although I thought I had covered all my bases. Striving badly for a solution, I stumbled upon http://danmarner.com/2013/05/28/Sencha-Touch-2-and-PhoneGap-integration.html. and found that `cordova.js` has to be added manually. Although pretty sure it would be, I checked whether this was the case in the APK. It wasn't. It was in the pre-build `index.html`, though:

```
<script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src=".sencha/app/microloader/development.js"></script>
```

So, the root cause is: a simple Copy&Paste error. The first script call with `id="microloader"` is replaced by the inline microloader during `sencha app build`. Thus, the link to `cordova.js` is lost during build. The correct code would have been

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src=".sencha/app/microloader/development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining Ext.blink as a function, so the eventlistener won't get added until that has run. Are you sure it will run before the device is actually ready?

I'm not sure, but perhaps you need to set the eventlistener directly at runtime, not deferred to a function call?

Comment: As per [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready): If you register the deviceready event when the device is already ready, the deviceready will fire immediately.